# utilize UCI_LimitStrength option in stockfish

Tags: chess, uci

I am working on a chess game and use UCI to communicate with stockfish 12. Right now I want to limit the engine's strength to a specific ELO rating. I know there are `UCI_LimitStrength` and `UCI_Elo` options in Stockfish, but these are commands. I wonder if there is any API that I can use to achieve my goal? I am currently using python-chess, which has a `depth` attribute to limit the engine strength, but I have no clue how does a depth match to a Elo rating. Thanks.

Comment: I saw you can pass parameters to the `popen_uci` method, maybe the solution lies there https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/c979f06732a6d31df6fe8af486bb41ea0ad21d1c/chess/engine.py#L2556